# Unable to retrieve embedded resource stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, embedded-resource

Using Visual Studio 2012, I am debugging a program to find out why loading a resource file using `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream` isn't working. The file is being copied to the project's bin folder correctly - but invoking `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` is reporting that the program is not running from there - it is running from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c37f9465\2be54367\assembly\dl3\c92e18ea\e852a1ef_ce6ad001`.

The program is a web service, and the error occurs in a DLL called `ConnectSystem.DLL` (another project in the same solution), and it is this file that resides in the Microsoft.NET folder.

If this is because of [Dynamic ASP.NET Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723(v=vs.140).aspx), which looks like the best explanation, can anyone think of a way I can incorporate my configuration file please?

Comment: Please show your relevant code.

Comment: XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
            d.Load(new System.IO.StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ConnectExternalWCF.App_Data.LabelPrintConfig.xml")));

Comment: I am beginning to think that my problem might be related to using IIS. The web service runs under IIS, and in the project properties Web setting page , it is set to use the Visual Studio Development server.

Comment: Looks as though it might have something to do with "Dynamic ASP.NET Compilation" - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources you are trying to load shouldn't be next to the assembly, it should be compiled into it. `GetManifestResourceStream` only reads resources from the assemblies themselves.

You can try to set the build action of the resource to `Embedded Resource`, and the file should end up in your assembly. The name may vary, usually it has the namespace as prefix. You could use Reflector to see what the actual name is.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Looks as though the problem is "shadow copying" ( http://www.ipreferjim.com/2012/04/asp-net-appdomains-and-shadow-copying/ ), and when reflection asks where the DLL is, it reports the cache location - and the resource file wasn't there. One minor point - the resource file Build Action (in the file's properties) had to be set to "Embedded Resource" rather than resource. Problem solved!

Comment: Okay. There won't be a resource file. It is embedded in the assembly. That's the entire purpose of it.